# RPC: C++11 Mechanism to de-serialize parameters for function calls

Tags: c++, rpc

EDIT2:  Updated code and godbolt link at bottom for final issue (parameters seem to be getting reversed)

EDIT:   for the vote to close on 'too many questions', please read the bolded section.  I have a general solution for everything except how to deserialize and call the function.  The rest is provided for background.

TL;DR:  I'm looking for a way to succinctly create a mechanism to serialize and de-serialize function parameters with as little cut/paste boilerplate as possible.

More context.   We have a custom ASIC that has multiple cores (lets assume identical) that we want to have the same software interface on each core, but marshal the calls over to the core responsible for the specific peripheral.  So on the client side, we'd call a function, wrap up the parameters, and pass to some IPC mechanism to be received by the server, unpacked, and the desired function call made on the , etc.

I have a semi-reasonable solution for serializing the parameters:

```
template<typename ... Args>
auto Serialize(uint32_t FunctionID, Args ...args )
{
    auto args_tuple = std::tuple<Args...>(args...);
    send_to_IPC_Pipe(FunctionID);
    //foreach tuple element
    //  send_to_IPC_Pipe(get<n>(args_tuple));
}

void EntryPoint(int a, float b, bool c)
{
    uint32_t uFunctionID = hash(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    Serialize(uFunctionID,a,b,c);
}
```

I realize that there will be rote copying of the `EntryPoint` construct for each entry point, but I can't see a way to get around that.

**But I'm a bit stuck on the mechanism to de-serialize and make its way back to a function call.**  Best I can think of is the following:
(NOTE:   we use constexpr literal operator to convert the function name to a 32 bit hash)

```
void OnServerSideRPCReceived()
{
      uint32_t uFunctionID = get_from_IPC_Pipe<uint32_t>();
      switch(uFunctionID):
      {
           case "EntryPoint"__hash:
               //somehow "automate" pulling the parameters from the 
               //IPC pipe and calling the local function of the same name
               break;
      }
}
```

Even though I THINK I can reliably know which function I need to call on the server, I'm not coming up with a clean way to use the function signature to drive what gets read from the IPC pipe.

Maybe something like...

```
    case "EntryPoint"_hash:
          Deserialize(EntryPoint);
          break;
```

where Deserialize is defined as something like...

```
template<typename F>
DeSerialize(F function)
{
    //somehow get all the parameters
    function(a,b,c);
}
```

**But I'm stuck at how to "auto" specialize based on the parameters of the passed in function.**  I'm pretty sure I could manually provide a template specialization for the different calling signatures, but it would be nice to have the template be able to do that automatically.

So, any suggestions?

---

EDIT:   simple example showing final issues to resolve

Godbolt link:  https://godbolt.org/z/KMa8dxjxf

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

class ByteQueue
{
    uint8_t storage[1024];
    uint8_t *writeptr;
public:        
    template<typename T>
    void push(T &data)
    {
        memcpy(writeptr,&data,sizeof(data));
        writeptr += sizeof(data);
    }
    template<typename T>
    void pull(T&data)
    {
        memcpy(&data,storage,sizeof(data));
        uint32_t uAmountToCopy = uintptr_t(writeptr)-uintptr_t(storage)-sizeof(data);
        memmove(storage,storage+sizeof(data),uAmountToCopy);
        writeptr -= sizeof(data);
    }
    ByteQueue() {
        writeptr = storage;
    }
};

ByteQueue g_ByteQueue;

template<typename T>
void send_to_IPC_Pipe(T first)
{
    g_ByteQueue.push(first);
}

template<typename T>
T get_from_IPC_Pipe()
{
    T var;
    g_ByteQueue.pull(var);
    return var;
}


namespace detail
{
    // FNV-1a 32bit hashing algorithm.
    inline constexpr uint32_t fnv1a_32(char const *s, size_t count) 
    {
        return count ? (fnv1a_32(s, count - 1) ^ s[count - 1]) * 16777619u : 2166136261u;
    }
}    // namespace detail

inline constexpr uint32_t operator"" _hash(const char *  s, size_t count)
{
    return detail::fnv1a_32(s, count);
}

constexpr uint32_t hash(char const *s,size_t count)
{
    return detail::fnv1a_32(s,count);
}

template<typename ... Args>
void Serialize(uint32_t FunctionID, Args ... args)
{
    send_to_IPC_Pipe(FunctionID);
    //some magical syntax for C++11
    int dummy[]= { (send_to_IPC_Pipe(args),0)...};
    //hide the warning
    (void)dummy;
}

template<typename ... Args>
void Invoke(void(*function)(Args...))
{
    function(get_from_IPC_Pipe<Args>()...);
}

void MyFunction(int a, int b, int c)
{
    printf("ClientSide: %s, %d, %d, %d\n",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,a,b,c);
    Serialize(hash(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,strlen(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__)),a,b,c);
}

void MyFunctionServerSide(int a, int b, int c)
{
    printf("ServerSide: %s, %d, %d, %d\n",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__,a,b,c);
}

void runRPCs()
{
    uint32_t uFunctionID = get_from_IPC_Pipe<uint32_t>();
    switch (uFunctionID)
    {
        case "void MyFunction(int, int, int)"_hash:
            Invoke(MyFunctionServerSide);
            break;
    }
}

int main()
{
    MyFunction(2,4,6);
    runRPCs();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is very limited. First, you can only marshal primitive types. Second, you serialize given *actual* argument types but deserialize according to the function's *signature*, you better make sure they are exactly the same (no implicit conversions of anything anywhere).

Comment: @n.m.   I appreciate the info.   I think, however, I'm capturing the arguments from 'inside' the function to be called and reconstitute those same types & values before calling the actual function based on its signature.  That means any implicit conversion issues would exist for calling the function directly.  (i.e. this serialize/deserialize shouldn't add any risk).   Clearly, though, there are limitations to parameter types (references will have issues, complex things like std::vector, etc as well), but I think these are sort of inherent with any RPC scheme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do both sides with pack expansions.

```
template<typename ... Args>
auto Serialize(uint32_t FunctionID, Args... args)
{
    send_to_IPC_Pipe(FunctionID);
    int dummy[] = { (send_to_IPC_Pipe(args), 0)... };
}   

template<typename ... Args>
void Invoke(void(*function)(Args...))
{
    function(get_from_IPC_Pipe<Args>()...);
}

void OnServerSideRPCReceived()
{
      uint32_t uFunctionID = get_from_IPC_Pipe<uint32_t>();
      switch(uFunctionID):
      {
           case "EntryPoint"_hash: Invoke(EntryPoint);
               break;
      }
}
```

Comment: `send_to_IPC_Pipe(args)...;` does not seem to compile.  (says `expected ';' before '...' token`).  Is that C++11 syntax or something later?

Comment: @RussSchultz oops, forgot that C++11 had less options for packs, you have to initialise a dummy variable

Comment: sorry, another comment when implementing.  I think I'm finding that the order of  calls to `send_to_IPC_Pipe`  is the same order of parameters as written, but the order of `get_from_IPC_Pipe` appears to be reverse order.  See my updated question for code and link to godbolt showing the output